# jQuery: Autocomplete with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I've seen this approached with a php script to fill the autocomplete..and didn't quite understand it. Anyhoo, I have a bunch of names and associated URLs to photos. I want to have the names as the autocomplete dictionary with their associated images...kinda like the facebook search. Don't really know where to start.
Thanks!

**Edit:**
By don't know where to start, I mean specific to the images.. I don't need to learn the alphabet lol. I have the textfield autocompleting with names and I just want to add photos beside the names, preferably clientside.

Comment: Start with learning javascript and html?

Comment: @zerkms snarky comment not terribly helpful for op.

Comment: @benauthor: It's not snarky at all, it's truthful. You have to walk before you run after all.

Comment: I have a working understanding of both. I have the regular autocomplete working, I just want to add photos. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @JoshDG: you add images with `<img src="..." />`, what's the problem?

Comment: @zerkms can you please put that in context? I have       $( "#request" ).autocomplete({source: keys}); I just don't know where to put that img tag

Comment: @JoshDG: we have no idea what `.autocomplete()` in your case means. There are billion autocomplete plugins for jquery

Comment: OH SORRY! OK thats where we're getting confused. I'm using the jquery UI autocomplete. I feel like we're not supposed to have extended comments like this. In the above code I pasted, keys is just a list of keys which are names, I have them in another object linked to image URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This autocomplete example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) on the jqueryui site might be useful for you as a starting point.

Assuming you've got your names and photo URLs in a database somewhere, the jqueryui autocomplete should work for you pretty smoothly if you use the 'source' option to point to a server-side script in whatever language you're comfortable working in, which just has to query your DB and return JSON.

Comment: Is there a way to do the images clientside? I have can encode my URL list in JSON (with names as keys).

Comment: @JoshDG: yes, images are displayed on client-side using `<img ... />` tag

Comment: That's even easier. look at example http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: That link should do it. I think what I want is that html extension link at the bottom of that page because I want each item in that drop down to have an image (like on facebook). Thanks!